# iphone access to song database/stats

Tags: iphone

Can an app that you develop interface with iTunes on the iPhone/iPod to get a name of a song or a list of the songs that are played the most by the owner of the iPhone or iPod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Media Player Framework, what information you can get about any particular song is limited to the `MPMediaItemProperty` values that Apple exposes. The [General Media Item Property Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211) are as follows:

```
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID;      // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType;         // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyTitle;             // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle;        // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtist;            // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist;       // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyGenre;             // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyComposer;          // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyIsCompilation;     // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyComments;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL;
```

As you can see, play count (or something similar) is not listed there, so the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

This has changed with the introduction of User-Defined Property Keys.

Refer to this question:
[ios get play count for items in the media library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261100/ios-get-play-count-for-items-in-the-media-library)