# ios get play count for items in the media library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am currently trying to categorise a users music collection and the ability to get the users most played songs/artists would greatly improve the user experience in the app. Is it possible to get the play count? and how would I go about doing it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MPMediaItem has the method:

```
- (id) valueForProperty: (NSString *) property
```

This method return the media property key that you want the corresponding value of. And one of the possibles values is MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount:

> The number of times the user has played the media item. Value is an
>   NSNumber object representing an NSUInteger data type.

You can check the doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaEntity/valueForProperty:).

Answer (score 3):

Should you want to find the user's most played track(s), you could:

1. Store all media items (i.e. `[[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] items]`) and their properties in a database (i.e. Core Data), fetch them with an [NSFetchRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html) and sort the results with [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
2. ...or use `[[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] items]` and [sort the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it) on the `MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount` property.

Option (1) is probably best, especially if you're looking to categorize the music collection (I guess (2) could be worse performance-wise too).

There's also [a similar answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570969/getting-the-most-played-track-out-of-the-ipod-libray-mpmediaquery) to help answer your question.

[Check out the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on MPMediaQueries.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Core Data they have a lot of methods for you to use. Check this out: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html